# Is there a way to set the niceness setting of spark executor processes?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a cluster of machines that I have to share with other processes. Lets just say I am not a nice person and want my spark executor processes to have a higher priority then other people's processes. How can I set that?

I am using StandAlone mode, v2.01, running on RHEL7

Comment: [The standalone cluster mode currently only supports a simple FIFO scheduler across applications.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/spark-standalone.html#resource-scheduling)

Comment: I don't mean a priority vs other spark applications on the same master, I mean other processes on the nodes. For example, other processes running applications such as HTCondor.

Comment: one way is to oversubscribe cores in cluster.

Comment: How do I oversubscribe the cores? Set partitions number to 3 x no of cores perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Spark does not currently (2.4.0) support `nice` process priorities. Grepping through the codebase, there is no usage of `nice`, and hence no easy to set process priority on executors using out-of-the-box Spark. It would be a little odd of Spark to do this, since it only assumes it can start a JVM, not that the base operating system is UNIX.

There are hacky ways to get around this that I do NOT recommend. For instance, if you are using Mesos as a resource manager, you could set `spark.mesos.executor.docker.image` to an image where java actually calls `nice -1 old-java "$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Allocate all the resources to the spark application leaving minimal
>   resource needed for os to run.

**A simple scenario :**
Imagine a cluster with six nodes running NodeManagers(Yarn Mode), each equipped with 16 cores and 64GB of memory. The NodeManager capacities, `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`, should probably be set to 63 * 1024 = 64512 (megabytes) and 15 respectively. We avoid allocating 100% of the resources to YARN containers because the node needs some resources to run the OS and Hadoop daemons. In this case, we leave a gigabyte and a core for these system processes.

Comment: The spark cluster is not using YARN. Second, it already busy with other workloads that are not spark related in any way.